# Projective line has genus 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

It is a well-known fact that projective line has genus $0$. However, I cannot deduce this fact from Riemann-Roch theorem and Serre duality. Let's recall these results

Let $X$ be smooth irreducible projective curve, $g$ be the genus of $X$ and $D$ a divisor on $X$ then

Riemann-Roch theorem: 
$$\dim H^0(X,D)-\dim H^1(X,D)=1-g+\deg(D)$$

Combining with Serre duality we have
$$\dim H^0(X,D)-\dim H^0(X,K_X-D)=1-g+\deg(D)$$ where $K_X$ is the canonical divisor.
We also know that $g=H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=H^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$. Let $D=K_X$ and $D=0$ respectively, we obtain degree of canonical divisor is $2g-2$ and of principal divisor is $0$.

In case of $\mathbb{P}^1$ every divisor $D$ is linear equivalent to $n \infty$ for some $n$. My idea is choosing appropriate divisor and using the formulas above to compute $g= H^1(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1})$ but maybe it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. Let $[x_0:x_1] \in \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\infty=[0:1]$, you mean $dz=dx_1/dx_0$?

Comment: All you need to do to calculate the genus here is to know the cohomology groups $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1})$ and $H^1(\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1})$, which are usually computed before Riemann-Roch and Serre Duality are introduced in most texts and courses. If you're unfamiliar with these computations, [here's](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XS) a reference. These are fundamental computations that you really should carefully work through at least once in you life and then cite with reckless abandon thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is using the Euler exact sequence, which shows that the canonical divisor $K_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ is equivalent to $-2\infty$, which gives you that $g=0$ by Riemann-Roch and Serre duality.

You can also calculate whatever homology groups you're interested in directly using the Cech complex, but that is more laborious.

Comment: Thank you @Irit. You mean Euler exact sequence here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_sequence? Can you explain in more detail why the canonical divisor is equivalent to $-2\infty$?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct sequence. For $\mathbb{P}^1$ it reads $0\to \Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to O(-1)\oplus O(-1)\to O(\mathbb{P}^1)\to 0$, taking determinant bundles gives that $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^1}\cong O(-2)$, so taking divisors gives that $K_{\mathbb{P}_1$} is equivalent to $-2\infty$.

Comment: Oh "determinant bundles" is new for me. Btw, thank you